# Why is a different binding object created each time?

Tags: ruby, local-variables

[RDoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Binding.html) explains that

> Objects of class `Binding` encapsulate the execution context at some particular place in the code and retain this context for future use. The variables, methods, value of `self`, and possibly an iterator block that can be accessed in this context are all retained.

For this purpose, it seems reasonable and useful if a single context had a unique binding object. However, Even in the exact same context, successively creating a binding object results in a different object each time:

```
binding # => #<Binding:0x007f29017cf8e0>
binding # => #<Binding:0x007f29017ccff0>
binding # => #<Binding:0x007f29017c8d38>
```

Why is this? Is there anything that would be more convenient with this feature?

One inconvenience I see with this feature is that when I do something that is dependent on the current context, there is no way other than to explicitly refer to a binding object. 
The last two lines in the following return an error because the binding object created by `binding` is not shared by another binding object created or by the implicit context.

```
b = binding
b.local_variable_set(:foo, "foo")

b.local_variable_get(:foo)       # => "foo"
binding.local_variable_get(:foo) # => error
foo                              # => error
```

Comment: it seems new context is treated by aury authors as to call to `binding` method each time. May be it is just because to simplify analysis of the new context, exactly to avoiding this analysis.

Comment: sorry that was ruby* =)

Answer (score 0):

See [Kernel#binding](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-binding):

> Returns a Binding object, describing the variable and method bindings **at the point** of call.

As I understand it, the Binding object is related to where you create it. So the `binding` may not check whether the context is different and just return a new binding of that *point*. If you want something deeper, you may have a look at the MRI implement [source/mri/proc.c#314](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/proc.c#314)